# What are great forty?

Tags: theravada

What are great forty? 
What are the great forty according to following Sutta.
I can identify 30.

Noble tenfold path with mundane and supermundane account for 20

Wrong tenfold path account for another 10.

What is the remaining 10?

=============

“Therein, bhikkhus, right view comes first. And how does right view come first? In one of right view, right intention comes into being; in one of right intention, right speech comes into being; in one of right speech, right action comes into being; in one of right action, right livelihood comes into being; in one of right livelihood, right effort comes into being; in one of right effort, right mindfulness comes into being; in one of right mindfulness, right concentration comes into being; in one of right concentration, right knowledge comes into being; in one of right knowledge, right deliverance comes into being. Thus, bhikkhus, the path of the disciple in higher training possesses eight factors, the arahant possesses ten factors.

https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/bodhi

Answer (score 4):

In one of **(R.1.1)** **right view**, wrong view (W.1.1) is abolished and the many evil unwholesome states (W.1.2) that originate with wrong view as condition are also abolished, and the **(R.1.2) many wholesome states that originate with right view as condition** come to fulfilment by development .... In one of **(R.10.1) right deliverance**, wrong deliverance (W.10.1) is abolished, and the many evil unwholesome states (W.10.2) that originate with wrong deliverance as condition are also abolished, and the **(R.10.2) many wholesome states that originate with right deliverance as condition** come to fulfilment by development.

> Thus, bhikkhus, there are **twenty factors on the side of the
>   wholesome** and **twenty factors on the side of the unwholesome**.

10 right factors + 10 wholesome states originating from 10 right factors + 10 wrong factors + 10 unwholesome states originating from 10 wrong factors = 40

Comment: What are these R.1.1 and W.1.1 etc.?

Comment: @SarathW Right and Wrong

Answer (score 1):

Following 10 factors

1. view
2. intention
3. speech
4. action
5. livelihood
6. effort
7. mindfulness
8. concentration
9. knowledge
10. liberation

are expanded 4 ways as:

1. right [view, intention, ..., liberation]
2. wrong [view, intention, ..., liberation]
3. wholesome state from the right [view, intention, ..., liberation]
4. unwholesome state from the wrong [view, intention, ..., liberation]

> The 20 factors on the unwholesome side are the 10 wrong factors and the
>   unwholesome states that originate from each. The 20 factors on the wholesome side are the 10 right factors and the wholesome states that originate from each

[Maha Cattarīsaka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/6.10-Maha-Cattarisaka-S-m117-piya.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

I read MN 117 as follows:

- 10 wholesome factors by developing (good) and abandoning (bad) = 20 wholesome
- 10 unwholesome factors by developing (bad) and abandoning (good) = 20 unwholesome

https://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=22062&p=485161&hilit=forty#p485161

Comment: Hi Chris. Is my analysis different to Suminda and DD?

Comment: I found DD's difficult to read/understand -- it took me a while to understand his numbering scheme (e.g. "R.1.1" etc.). Suminda's is clearer, easier to read. I think yours is the same but is the easiest to read and understand, isn't that so, or do you think yours is different?

Comment: Agree. I could not understand DD so I thought he is saying something diffrent.-)